# Why there is no warning when function prototype in definition and declaration are not the same in c?

Tags: c

I have three files, `test.c`, `a.h`, `a.c`. `test.c` call a function declared in `a.h`, and `a.c` define the function. But the funcion in `a.c` are different from `a.h` in the return value and the parameter. Either case, there is no warning from my `gcc` and there is some result. Why?

In my `test.c`

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int x = a();
  printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

In my `a.h`

```
int a();
```

In my `a.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void a(int a)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

in my terminal:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c a.c  // no warning
$ ./test
1
2
```

Comment: `int a();` declare a function a that take an unspecified number of argument and return an int, and you didn't include your header file in `a.c`...

Comment: I think that value is being taken from uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Stargateur -- `int a();` is deprecated now anyway, isn't it?

Comment: And where does the value of  `1 2` come from?

Comment: So, it use old c declare, I see, thanks @Stargateur

Comment: After include header in `a.c`, gcc gave me the error now.

Comment: @DavidBowling I'm sure in C++ it's deprecated but I'm not sure for C, https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.7p3. Whatever this feature is no longer used or useful.

Comment: @Stargateur -- This is what I was thinking of: [The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6)

Comment: @DavidBowling: In C terminology, it is obsolescent, not deprecated, meaning it may be considered for removal in a future version of the standard and its use is discouraged, but it is a part of the language.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- right. I couldn't remember what was the case until I looked it up.

Comment: Make it  habit to always pass to GCC `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to enable more warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the a.h being included in a.c, the **compiler** doesn't know it's a problem.  So you won't get any compile issues at all.  Each gets its own .o file and everyone is happy.

The compiler expects `a()` to return an `int` so it has the machine code grab the result off the stack (or probably some register).

The compiler expects `a()` to have a parameter, so it has the machine code grab the parameter off the stack (again, probably a register).

Then the linker comes along and puts them all together.  It doesn't **know** that there's an issue, but it makes the call to `a()` work.

So you get values that are left over on the register (or stack).  And hopefully you're in a protected environment so that you're not getting **some other user's** information.